# PHP file_get_content() of xml file return weird numbers

Tags: php, json, xml, parsing

I'm trying to get content of XML file in php using file_get_content. But it returns me weird numbers like

```
1.2610.09 1.351 1.351 1.261 1.261 1.261 0.09 1.351 1.261 0.00 1.0010.07 1.071 1.071 1.001 1.001 1.001
```

XML Example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso_8859-1"?>
<day xmlns="x-schema:..\schema_ej.xml" FILE="80919004.010">
<trs F1068="SALE" F254="2018-09-19" F253="2018-09-19T07:09:11" F1056="004" F1057="010" F1035="07:08:50" F1036="07:09:11"
F1032="1672" F1764="00001663" F1185="24" F1126="202" F1127="MAX">
<r F1101="1"><itm F01="0000000007001" F02="COLADA EA" F04="60" F03="60" F81="1" F1007="1.26" F1006="1"/><F65>1.26</F65><F64>1</F64><F1263>0.09</F1263><key in="202" fn="10777"/><key in="202" fn="10762"/><key in="202" fn="10710"/><key in="202" fn="10746"/><key in="202" fn="10735"/><key in="202" fn="10775"/><key in="202" fn="10725"/><key in="202" fn="10200"/><key fn="710"/></r>
<r F1101="2"><fct F1063="101" F02="Cash" F113=""/><F65>1.35</F65><F64>1</F64><key fn="720"/><key in="1.35" fn="101"/></r>
<t><tlz F1034="2" F02="TOTAL SALES"/><F65>1.35</F65><F64>1</F64></t>
<t><tlz F1034="3" F02="Net Sales"/><F65>1.26</F65><F64>1</F64></t>
<t><tlz F1034="7" F02="Discountable Sales"/><F65>1.26</F65><F64>1</F64></t>
<t><tlz F1034="21" F02="Taxable 1"/><F65>1.26</F65><F64>1</F64></t>
<t><tlz F1034="22" F02="Tax 1"/><F65>0.09</F65></t>
<t><tlz F1034="1201" F02="Cash"/><F65>1.35</F65><F64>1</F64></t>
<t><tlz F1034="3415" F02="Admissible spending"/><F65>1.26</F65><F64>1</F64></t>
<t><tlz F1034="29999" F02="BALANCE"/><F65>0.00</F65></t>
</trs>
</day>
```

My ultimate aim is to convert xml to json.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the PHP code that is reading the file. It acts like in your output you are trying to echo the contents out to the browser. If so, the browser is treating the XML as HTML. When this is output to the browser, the tags do not appear. DO a "view source" and see if you see your XML. Pro Tip: do not try to parse your own XML. Use an XML parser to read the file into an object, then write the object with json_encode or similar. Should only be 4-5 lines of code.

Comment: If you're echo'ing the result and viewing it in your browser, that's not weird at all. Your browser is ignoring all the XML tags it doesn't recognise and displays only the numbers inside them. If you view the page source, your XML should all be there.

Comment: @mrunion & @ rickdenhaan you're right. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

File_get_contents for getting a content and then: SimpleXML for parsing XML.

```
$xmlFILE = file_get_contents('PATHTOFILE.xml');
$simpleXml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo $simpleXml->__toString();


function XML2JSON($xml) {

        function normalizeSimpleXML($obj, &$result) {
            $data = $obj;
            if (is_object($data)) {
                $data = get_object_vars($data);
            }
            if (is_array($data)) {
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $res = null;
                    normalizeSimpleXML($value, $res);
                    if (($key == '@attributes') && ($key)) {
                        $result = $res;
                    } else {
                        $result[$key] = $res;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $result = $data;
            }
        }
        normalizeSimpleXML(simplexml_load_string($xml), $result);
        return json_encode($result);
    }
```